# "In the presence" or "in presence"

Tags: definite-articles

I am confused about how to use *in the presence*. Here I have written a sentence in which I think *the* before *presence* should be omitted.

> This situation might be more critical **in the presence** of long edges,
>   although we restrict the irregular shape boundary to minimize the
>   complexity.

Comment: Please support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's fine as you've written it.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with you, I think the word "The" fits here.  I think "in presence" is sort of awkward and incorrect.  In the presence of is definite, meaning The presence.  Presence is a definite article, like The Shirt The Car, The X.  It